# Delete a file which is used by another process in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to delete one file which was used by certain another process of my Application.
So its giving an Error that file is used by certain another process.

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{

    DirectoryInfo NewDir = new DirectoryInfo(imagefolderpath1);
    FileInfo[] files = NewDir.GetFiles("*.jpg");
    foreach (var item in files)
    {
        string strFile = imagefolderpath1 + "\\" + item.ToString();
        if (File.Exists(strFile))
        {

            File.Delete(strFile);
        }
    }

}
```

How should i solve this problem can you please help me????

Comment: You have to release the file in the other processes at first.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of "sweeping rug from under feet" questions today... btw If the file doesn't exist, file.delete will just do nothing so no need to check it

Comment: Close the process that's using it and then delete the file.

Comment: Is file on another (remote) machine?

Comment: Even if `Delete` did "do something" if the file didn't exit, there's a race between `Exists` and `Delete` which means the result of `Exists` could well be stale by the time the `Delete` comes around.

Comment: The 66% odds for a question like this is that it is actually *your* process that prevents it from being deleted.  Forgetting to call Dispose() on images is a very common mistake.  The other 33% is "you're out of luck".

Answer (score 3):

You need to kill the process which is causing this issue by the following code, something like :

```
 string fileName = @"D:\pathname.jpg";//Path to locked file

Process Handletool = new Process();
Handletool.StartInfo.FileName = "handle.exe";
Handletool.StartInfo.Arguments = fileName+" /accepteula";
Handletool.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Handletool.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Handletool.Start();           
Handletool.WaitForExit();
string outputTool = Handletool.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

string matchPattern = @"(?<=\s+pid:\s+)\b(\d+)\b(?=\s+)";
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(outputTool, matchPattern))
{
    Process.GetProcessById(int.Parse(match.Value)).Kill();
}
```

u can get Handle.exe from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx

Comment: Thats just asking for trouble... Your program may be fine but you've screwed the other one up.. Grumbler85's original comment is the only real answer..

Comment: But what if the the other process using the file is no longer required (as per the requirement), then either that process has to be manually killed or programatically

Comment: Great, now how can you determine that?

Comment: But still I agree with you, but it is upto the user who has to decide

Answer (score 0):

The file needs to be released by the other program before it can be deleted. You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find out what is locking it if you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

you can't access the file used by another process. But if it's not critical for you app to do this later, you can do this in the System.AppDomain.ProcessExit event handler.
just add the file to a centrally managed list and register your cleanup routine like here:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(deleteFilesIfPossibleNow);
```

in the handler you must still handle exceptions if files are still accessed from another processes.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using _FormClosed you might want to try launching the form from your other code like this:

```
DirectoryInfo NewDir;
FileInfo[] files;

using (var form = new Form1())
{
    var result = form.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.Close)
    {
        NewDir = new DirectoryInfo(imagefolderpath1);
        files = NewDir.GetFiles("*.jpg");
    }
}

foreach(var item in files) { 
    string strFile = imagefolderpath1 + "\\" + item.toString();
    File.Delete(strFile);
}
```

i wasn't a hundred % sure how your program is meant to work but you can grab information from the forms before they close then close the files they were using after with this kind of method